# cut and compare string in file

Tags: linux, cut

I have file that contaian the following lines :

```
3 5 asd/sdf/rdc fgd/ghw/rtt
4 7 axd/sdf/rdc axd/ghw/ert
8 2 drf/sdf/uhg fgd/ghw/gcd
```

I want to compare only the first names in coloums 3 & 4 and print if match or not - result should be :

```
3 5 asd/sdf/rdc fgd/ghw/rtt diff
4 7 axd/sdf/rdc axd/ghw/ert equal
8 2 drf/sdf/uhg fgd/ghw/gcd diff
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```bash
awk '{ split($3,a,"/"); split($4,b,"/"); $(NF+1) = a[1] == b[1] ? "equal" : "diff" }; 1' file
```

This splits the 3rd and 4th fields on the slashes and then adds a new field depending on whether the first element of the split-up strings are equal or different.

The trailing `1` at the end causes the modified record to be outputted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with standard `sed`:

```
sed 's_$_ diff_;s_\( [^/]*/\)\(.*\1.*\)diff_\1\2equal_'
```

- pessimisticly, we always add  `diff` first with `s_$_ diff_`
- then we `s`ubstitute the `diff` with `equal`, if the sequence from the whitespace to the next slash  `[^/]*/` is repeated (`\1`) later in the line

Comment: great , it's working , thanks you very much

Comment: @OrenHamama Then please mark the question as solved by accepting one of the answers.